# flex mobile: how to use skinClass and softKeyboardType?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, flex4.6, flex-mobile

My flex 4.6 mobile application uses a customized skinClass.
Trouble is the softKeyboardType seems not to work anymore when using skinClass differant than the default one.

Any idea how to combine both ?

```
<s:TextInput id="login_txt" skinClass="skins.TextInputSkin" softKeyboardType="email"/>
```

(where skins.TextIputSKin is my own skin: I need to keep it)

It seems this quetsion is quite similar: [Flex Mobile textInput in scroller text lag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335337/flex-mobile-textinput-in-scroller-text-lag)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code; it is impossible to give you complete guidance.

But, you can only set the softKeyboardType if you are using [StageText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StageText.html).  This was introduced in AIR 3 according to the docs.  The default [Flex 4.5 TextInput skin](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/skins/mobile/TextInputSkin.html) does not use StageText; but the default [Flex 4.6 TextInput skin](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/skins/mobile/StageTextInputSkin.html) does.

I have no idea what your custom Skin uses.  If you built a skin class from scratch, you'll have to re-write it to use StageText.  If you are extending or modifying the Flex 4.5 skin; then you'll have to re-work it to use StageText.  If you are extending or modifying the Flex 4.6 skin; then softKeyboardType should work.

Comment: <s:TextInput id="login_txt" skinClass="skins.TextInputSkin" softKeyboardType="email"/>

 (flex4.6 and softKeyBoard opens a normal keyboard)

Comment: It seems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335337/flex-mobile-textinput-in-scroller-text-lag deals with same troubles.